# How can i make my help command "reset" Without making a million wait_fors? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is my help command:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['cmd', 'commands'])
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.blurple())
 
    embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="This is a list of everything Otay! can do! If you need additional help with Otay! join the [**support server**](https://discord.gg/Wa9DpJGEKv)", color=0x7289da)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/776181059757932615/784819540496351233/otay2.png")
    embed.add_field(name='`` ***Fun***', value='`8ball`, `coinflip`, `dice`, `joke`, `say`, `fact`, `ss`', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='`⚒️` ***Moderation***', value='`kick`, `ban`, `unban`, `nick`, `purge`, `slowmode`, `mute`, `unmute`, `lock`, `unlock`', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='`⚠️` ***Setup***', value='`prefix`, `welcome`', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='`️` ***Games***', value='`rps`, `tictactoe`', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='`` ***Giveaway***', value='`gstart`', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='`` ***Images***', value='`cat`, `dog`, `fox`, `koala`, `panda`, `meme`, `blursed`', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='`` ***Utilities***', value='`avatar`, `ping`, `poll`, `serverinfo`, `botinfo`, `userinfo`, `bitcoin`, `snipe`, `createinvite`, `password`', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="`` ***Ticket***", value="`configureticket`", inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(icon_url=f"https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/776181059757932615/784819540496351233/otay2.png", text=ctx.author)
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
    def checkifnotbot(reaction, user):
        return user != client.user
 
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('⚒️')
    await msg.add_reaction('⚠️')
    await msg.add_reaction('️')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
 
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=checkifnotbot)
 
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "":
      embedfun=discord.Embed(title="``Help Fun", color=0x7298da)
      await msg.edit(embed=embedfun)
      await msg.clear_reactions()
      await msg.add_reaction('↩️')
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == "⚒️":
      embedmod=discord.Embed(title="`⚒️`Help Moderation", color=0x7298da)
      await msg.edit(embed=embedmod)
      await msg.clear_reactions()
      await msg.add_reaction('↩️')
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == "⚠️":
      embedsetup=discord.Embed(title="`⚠️`Setup", color=0x7289da)
      embedsetup.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
      await msg.edit(embed=embedsetup)
      await msg.clear_reactions()
      await msg.add_reaction('↩️')
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == "️":
      embedgames=discord.Embed(title="`️Help Games`", color=0x7289da)
      await msg.edit(embed=embedgames)
      await msg.clear_reactions()
      await msg.add_reaction('↩️')
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == "":
      embedgiveaway=discord.Embed(title="``Help Giveaway", color=0x7298da)
      await msg.edit(embed=embedgiveaway)
      await msg.clear_reactions()
      await msg.add_reaction('↩️')
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == "":
      embedimages=discord.Embed(title="``Help Images", color=0x7298da)
      embedimages.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
      await msg.edit(embed=embedimages)
      await msg.clear_reactions()
      await msg.add_reaction('↩️')
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == "":
      embedlinks=discord.Embed(title="``Links", color=0x7289da)
      await msg.edit(embed=embedlinks)
      await msg.clear_reactions()
      await msg.add_reaction('↩️')
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == "":
      embedutils=discord.Embed(title="``Help Utilities", color=0x7298da)
      embedutils.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
      await msg.edit(embed=embedutils)
      await msg.clear_reactions()
      await msg.add_reaction('↩️')
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == "":
      embedticket=discord.Embed(title="``Help Ticket", color=0x7289da)
      await msg.edit(embed=embedticket)
      await msg.clear_reactions()
      await msg.add_reaction('↩️')
 
    def checkifbot(reaction, user):
        return user != client.user
 
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=checkifbot)
 
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "↩️":
      await msg.edit(embed=embed)
      await msg.clear_reactions()
```

**What i want to happen** The embed "resets" it adds all the reactions again and just worked like if you typed `-help`.
**My problem** I don't know how to make it edit to the normal help command, because if it edits back and you need to add the reactions again you need to make like a million `wait_for`s
**What i've tried**

```py
    def checkifbot(reaction, user):
        return user != client.user
 
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=checkifbot)
 
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "↩️":
      await msg.edit(embed=embed)
      await msg.clear_reactions()
```

Problem with this is that i need to make so many `wait_for`s because if people want to see another category they have to click the reaction again.

And i tried doing this but this just sends it again and doesnt edit it

```py
    def checkifbot(reaction, user):
        return user != client.user
 
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=checkifbot)
 
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "↩️":
      await help(ctx)
```

So is there a way to do something like: `await msg.edit(help)(ctx)`? Or how can i solve this problem?

Comment: The pastebin link is private, and have you considered using [menus](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus)?

Comment: I edited it. What do you mean with menus?

Comment: read up on the link i sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by creating a simple get_help function, that is

```py
async def get_help(ctx):
   return embed
   # whatever u are currently doing in help(ctx), but return embed instead of sending
  
async def add_reactions(msg, ctx):
   #add reactions
   #add wait_for
   
  

async def help(ctx):
   msg = await ctx.send(embed=get_help(ctx))
   await add_reactions(msg, ctx)
   def checkifbot(reaction, user):
        return msg.id == reaction.message.id and user != client.user #improved check
 
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=checkifbot)
 
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "↩️":
      await msg.edit(embed = get_help(ctx))
```

However, you need not go through this much hassle and use discord.py's [HelpCommand](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#help-commands). which might be easier to implement and modify as per need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But when i try do do this it says Undefined variable msg because i use msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed) https://imgur.com/a/SUS7sNZ

Comment: Improved my answer, and again using discord.py's helpcommand would make your job much easier